# Simple jQuery if statement, API returns 'null'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the Sunlight Congress API to pull a list of representatives, I'd like to return folks' nicknames if they are used. If a representative doesn't use a nickname, the API returns 'null'.

I'm messing up the syntax for the if statement. Here's my most recent misguided approach:

```
if (rep.nickname == 'null'){myFolks += rep.first_name + ' ';}
```

Here's the full context:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#rep-lookup').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $results = $('#rep-lookup-results'),
        zipcode = $('#txt-zip').val(),
        apiKey = '_YOUR_API_KEY';

    var requestURL = 'http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?callback=?';

    // collect the data

    $.getJSON(requestURL, {
        'apikey' : apiKey,
        'zip' : zipcode,
    }, function(data){
        if (data.results && data.results.length > 0) {

            var myFolks = '<p>Here are your Congress folk:</p>';

            $.each(data.results, function(i, rep) {
                    myFolks += '<p>';
                    myFolks += '<a href="' + rep.contact_form + '" target="_blank">';
                    myFolks += rep.nickname;
                        if (rep.nickname == 'null'){myFolks += rep.first_name + ' ';}
                    myFolks += rep.last_name + ' ';
                    myFolks += '</a>';
                    myFolks += '</p>';
            });

            myFolks += '<p>Please write to them in support of this legislation.</p>';

            $results.html(myFolks);
        } else {
            $results.html('<p>None found for zip code ' + zipcode + '. Please try again.</p>');
        }
    });

});
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the API returns the *string* `"null"`? It may return the `null` object instead.

Comment: also you are using it before you even check if it exists or not

Comment: `myFolks += (rep.nickname && rep.nickname !== "null") ? rep.nickname : rep.first_name + ' ';` ?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, you're right. It's returning the object not a string. By taking the quotes out, I'm able to get the first_name. Now I need to get "null" out of the output when the representative doesn't have a nickname. Probably something like an else if...

Comment: Thnx, @tomcreighton that works! I need to get use to one line if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myFolks += (rep.nickname && rep.nickname !== "null") ? rep.nickname : rep.first_name + ' ';
```

via: @tomcreighton